# Unity 3D - Why does my button need to be clicked twice to work?

Tags: unity, c#, gui

My goal is to go back and forth between a series of animations by clicking left and right arrow UI buttons. I wrote this C# script and the "next" button (which executes `AddInt()` on click) works as intended, however the "previous" button (which calls `ReduceInt()` on click), needs to be clicked twice to work. Is this a glitch or is something wrong with my code?

```
public class update_animator_parameter_int : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator gameobject_animator;
    public string int_parameter;
    public int max_int;
    public int current_int=0;

    void Start(){
        gameobject_animator = GetComponent<Animator>();}

    public void AddInt(){
          current_int++;
          if (current_int > max_int){current_int = 0;}
          gameobject_animator.SetInteger(int_parameter, current_int);}


    public void ReduceInt(){
          current_int--;
          if (current_int < 0){current_int = max_int;}
          gameobject_animator.SetInteger(int_parameter, current_int);}
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the inspector settings for your buttons? The script seems fine. Also how are you checking the results? Is it through the inspector or do you have a UI which shows the current_int value? If it's on the UI it's possible that the execution order in Unity is causing the issue.

Comment: You should do some basic debugging since there is not enough information. Add a log right after changing current_int in both functions, and then you'll see the exact flow of current_int, and try to understand what is happening.

Comment: Could it be a problem with your animation controller?